# phpquery - simulate browser click

Tags: php, phpquery

How to simulate browser click using phpquery framework?

I have the following code, but the click desn't seem to work

```
    phpQuery::$ajaxAllowedHosts = "www.godaddy.com"; 
    phpQuery::browserGet('http://www.godaddy.com/', 'myCallback');

    function myCallback($browser) {
        echo "myCallback" . PHP_EOL;
        $browser->WebBrowser('myCallback2')->find('#searchDomainName')->val("mydomain")->end()->find('#searchButton')->click();
    }
    function myCallback2($browser) {
        echo "myCallback2" . PHP_EOL;
        print $browser;
    }
```

And the code never reached `myCallback2`. Moreover, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function unparse_url() in D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\phpQuery\phpQuery\phpQuery\plugins\WebBrowser.php on line 360

Comment: I found this 'unparse_url` function: http://pastebin.com/5fp9vxar

Comment: tnx very ymuch!! the click now works, but it doesn't navigate me to the needed page... hm...